# Rails - good tool to create a scheduled background process which will regularly retrieve messages from twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background

Background Job gets mentioned a lot but all the tutorials I've seen seem to indicate that its for queuing jobs which are created by some external event such as a user clicking "Send mail".

But what about when you have code that needs to scheduled to run every 30 seconds to listen for new messages from twitter?

Normally rake is recommended for set in stone schedules but it inst so efficient for frequent jobs as it has to to load the entire rails app each time.

Can anyone recommend anything for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DelayedJob](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) allows you to schedule jobs to run at a particular time.

Comment: excellent, yes I figured out that you simply have to call the job again at the end of the perform method to achieve this. as per 

http://gist.github.com/260779

thank you very much